# How do you locate the source location of an Rsync process

Tags: linux, rsync, rhel

I have a text file being written to by an external Rsync process.  Is there any command i can use to monitor the process when it is running to obtain the source of the data being written.

All external systems admin are advising their system is not sending this data.

tried to identify by using netstat, but there are too many connections open to pin point with 100% accuracy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the destination machine, you can run `lsof` on the file in question to identify the process that writes it. Given it, you might find the port that this process is using and then to find what process runs on the source host. However this is pretty brittle. Consider using some other way to pass this information.